# How to test Python code for job scheduler?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, cluster-computing, job-scheduling

I'd like to write some tests for my Python code that manages several supercomputer job schedulers (like Slurm, PBS, Torque) and I don't want my tests to be run on any cluster with an actual job scheduler. Is there some Python library with mock objects for job schedulers?

For example, I want to test a method that views information about pending or running jobs, e.g. using `squeue` for Slurm or `qstat` for PBS.

Comment: What is job scheduler in this context? Celery? What is the built-in mock library missing?

Comment: @jordanm, edited.